# How to split string in multiple columns in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in with a column that has values like this:

```
["L", "L", "L", "D", "L", "D", "L", "L", "L", "D"] ,
```

I have to add it in another table which will be 10 columns and response will be 1 for character "L" , 0 for character "D".

My column names will be dynamic as the string contains 240 items of L and D. In the above example, only 10 are present. Column name will be item1, item2 and so on.

Comment: Will this string always contain the same number of items?

Comment: Firstly, *why* do you need to do this?  What are the different columns representing and why is this data not being recorded as rows?

Comment: @ldo Gal - Yes Same no of items

Comment: @iamdave - Client want to the data in that format to analysis . the columns representing the boolean value 1 for L and 0 for D . The one string recorded as one row, I want to split in columns with that column names like item1, item2 and so on.

Comment: There are numerous questions and answers on SO about string splitting. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @HoneyBadger - I tried and succeed to split string upto "L" only , But not able to dynamically for large no of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `XML` node method have you tried ever

```
select distinct
      case (a.value ('/A[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when '"L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column1],
      case (a.value ('/A[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when ' "L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column2],
      case (a.value ('/A[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when ' "L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column3],
      case (a.value ('/A[4]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when ' "L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column4],
      case (a.value ('/A[5]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when ' "L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column5],
      case (a.value ('/A[6]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when ' "L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column6],
      case (a.value ('/A[7]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when ' "L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column7],
      case (a.value ('/A[8]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when ' "L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column8],
      case (a.value ('/A[9]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when ' "L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column9],
      case (a.value ('/A[10]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) when ' "L"' THEN 1 WHEN ' "D"' THEN 0 END  [Column10]

      from 
(
    SELECT CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@DATA, '[', ''), ']', ''), ',', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) AS Data 
    --FROM <table_name>
) A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/A') as split(a)
```

Result :

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9 Column10
    1       1       1       0       1       0       1        1      1       0
```

Comment: yes , its helped me at initial stage , but now i have to convert that "L" to 1 and "D" to 0

Comment: use `case` or `replace`

Comment: @KulOmkar try edited solutions with `case` expression